# How to create 3-tier symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I want to show Features in QGIS taking account of three different factors. These are for wind farms and I want to show:

1. The height of the turbines (eg. up to 100m, 100-150m, 150-200m & over 200m - using differnt symbols - circle, triangle, etc);
2. The stage of development (eg. operational, under constuction, approved awaiting construction & seeking approaval - probably with different colours);
3. The overall size of the WF (up to 100MW, 100-200MW, 200-300MW etc - probably by the size of the symbol).

Is this do-able? What's the easiest way to do it?

Comment: I think this question is clear and focused enough to be reopened. It does not ask three different questions, but how to achieve a combined symbology, based on three conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the three conditions separately and use data driven override (Epsilon symbol: `ε`) on the right sight of the entries for size, color and symbol shape in the symbolization:

1. For shape, use an expression like:

   ```
    case 
    when floor ("hight"/100)>3 then 'square' else 'circle'
    end
   ```
2. For stage of development, use data driven override and set an expression like:

   ```
    case 
    when stage=  'operational' then 'red' 
    when stage=  'under construction' then 'blue'
    end
   ```
3. For size, use data driven override and use assistant, based on the field `size`.

[image]

Comment: For conditions with only true/false it is better to use `if`

Comment: Of course! But the question suggests that there are more categories (not true/fasle). To make things a bit shorter, I opted to just create two conditions that can be expanded on the pattern presented, so it is just for demonstration.

Comment: Thanks Babel. You have provided me with sufficient guidance to be able to achieve what I require. I appreciate more categories are required. 
I don't really understand why the question was closed - while others may not like the question, I feel it's a valid question.

Comment: I don't know why exactly the question was closed, seems to be OK to me. Sometimes it helps to post a screenshot to show how the result should look like. By the way: this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer if it solved your problem and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers